# cannot create google sitemap for Magento 2nd storefront

Tags: xml, magento, sitemap

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this problem...  I have my magento install at showcarsign.com and i'm also running a 2nd storefront with the install at showcarboards.com.  I can generate a sitemap for showcarsign.com no problem (showcarsign.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml).  But when I go to create the sitemap for showcarboards.com  I get the following error:

> Path "/sitemap/sitemap1.xml" is not available and cannot be used.

This is really strange... checked the directiory and file (I created a blank file) and they're both writable.  Am I missing something???

Comment: What method are you using for creating the sitemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Website subfolder in sitemap folder. For example:

```
showcarsign.com/carsign/sitemap.xml
showcarboards.com/carboards/sitemap.xml
```

You can read more in detail from the following links:

http://www.freshwebservices.com/blog/107-magento-multi-domain-sitemaps
https://oldwildissue.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/magento-google-sitemap-generation-for-multistore-installation/

Hope this help!!